# How to make correct pagination with GET parameters?

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-8

I am doing data output with pagination on laravel. Everything works great. I have my own pagination template. It's written like this:

`{{ $houses->links('catalogs.paginate') }}`

However, when I still search for data on the page by some parameters, the GET parameters do not get into pagination.

I tried to write like this:

{{ $houses->links('catalogs.paginate')->withQueryString() }}

Or

controller
...

```
public function Category($cat, Request $request) {
$houses = House::with('areas')->where('format_house', '=', $format_house)->paginate(4)->appends(request()->query());
return view('category_catalog', compact('title', 'houses'));
}
```

Maket

`{{ $houses->links('catalogs.paginate') }}`

Nothing helps. How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

{{ $houses->appends($_GET)->links('catalogs.paginate') }}

OR

{{ $houses->appends(request()->query())->links('catalogs.paginate') }}

Answer (score 1):

You're already close, the arrangement of the methods you're calling is incorrect, you must call the `links` method last.

```
$houses->paginate(15)->withQueryString()->links('catalogs.paginate')
```

OR

```
$houses->paginate(15)->appends(request()->query())->links('catalogs.paginate')
```

Comment: Did not help. The problem remains unresolved.

Comment: Maybe it's because there are a lot of GET parameters? There are about ten of them.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What do you mean its not working? The GET parameters are not being passed?

Comment: The page has a data search form in which the "action" is empty, i.e. it refers to the same page. When I run the form, the page in the browser is displayed the same only with GET parameters. However, I don't see any GET parameters in pagination, except for one "page". Here is such a problem. There are no error messages.